# Angular8: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive

Tags: typescript, angular8

My template - I don't need any form in my template (app-multiselect is our own dropdown)

```
<div class="frameworks frameworks-container">
  <div class="frameworks__header__filters">

    <div class="frameworks__header__filters__row">
      <div class="frameworks__header__filters__row">

        <div
          class="frameworks__header__label frameworks__header__label__top frameworks__header__label__frameworks">
          FILTERS
        </div>
        <div class="frameworks__header__filters__column">

          <div class="frameworks__header__filters__row frameworks__header__filters__row__wrap">
            <app-multiselect
              [id]="'calendar'"
              *ngIf="yearsList"
              formControlName="calendar"
              class="companies-selector"
              [defaultText]="calendarText"
              [data]="yearsList"
              [showSearchFilter]="false"
              [order]="'DESC'"
              [singleSelection]="true"
              [customClass]="'dropdown-center'"
            ></app-multiselect>

            <app-multiselect
              class="companies-selector"
              *ngIf="companies"
              [singleSelection]="true"
              [defaultText]="allCompaniesLabel"
              [data]="companies"
              [customClass]="'dropdown-center__lazy'"
              [lazy]="true"
            ></app-multiselect>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <h3>To access a survey, please select an icon below:</h3>

    <div class="framework__icon">
      <div class="item" *ngFor="let framework of allFrameworks">
        <div class="framework-name">
          <p class="framework-name">{{framework.itemName}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="status">
          <p>Data awaiting your review</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the error:

> FrameworksSceneComponent.html:14 ERROR Error: formControlName must be
> used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a
> formGroup
> directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).
>
> ```
>       Example:
>
>       
>     <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
>       <input formControlName="firstName">
>     </div>
>
>     In your class:
>
>     this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
>        firstName: new FormControl()
>     });
>     at Function.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.ReactiveErrors.controlParentException
> ```
>
> (forms.js:1558)
> at FormControlName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControlName._checkParentType
> (forms.js:5979)
> at FormControlName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControlName._setUpControl
> (forms.js:5983)
> at FormControlName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControlName.ngOnChanges
> (forms.js:5905)
> at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:19337)
> at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:27597)
> at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:27559)
> at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:28193)
> at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:28153)
> at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (FrameworksSceneComponent.html:14)

Anyone knows what's wrong with my template? I'd like to have a subpage with 2 dropdowns, after choosing some value from them the results on the page should change (after fetching data from service)

Comment: You should define your formgroup into your templete. Why do you use formControlName if you dont need a form in your template? If you have a reactive form in your parent component, child component must be used as fromcontrol as well to not break the chain. To accomplish that, you can use NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR in your child component.

Comment: I think I didn't notice the formControlName in my app-multiselect -> it seems to be working now without any errors... Thanks @cagcak!